# CORS at express level or Nginx level or both? Do both http and https need separate handling?

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, cors

```
import { NODE_ENV } from 'common/constants';

export function getAllowedOrigins() {
  // https://github.com/expressjs/cors/issues/272#issuecomment-1186236472
  let allowedOrigins: string[] = [];
  if (NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    allowedOrigins = ['http://www.example.local', 'https://www.example.local'];
  } else if (NODE_ENV === 'test') {
    allowedOrigins = [
      'http://staging.example.com',
      'https://staging.example.com',
    ];
  } else if (NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    allowedOrigins = ['http://www.example.com', 'https://www.example.com'];
  }
  return allowedOrigins;
}
```

- I am trying to setup cors on my node.js express app with the above file

Here is my express app file

```
...
const app = express();

app.use(rTracer.expressMiddleware());
app.use(requestLogger);

app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: getAllowedOrigins(),
  }),
);
...
```

- My local development, test and production environments run on localhost:8000
- I also have a docker development that runs on api.example.local behind nginx using self signed https certificates
- My production environment that ultimately runs on AWS with certbot powered https behind nginx

This is what my final production nginx.conf file that runs on AWS looks like

```
# Generated by nginxconfig.io
# See nginxconfig.txt for the configuration share link

user                 nginx;
pid                  /tmp/nginx.pid;
worker_processes     auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile 65535;

# Load modules
include              /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    multi_accept       on;
    worker_connections 65535;
}

http {
    charset                utf-8;
    sendfile               on;
    tcp_nopush             on;
    tcp_nodelay            on;
    server_tokens          off;
    log_not_found          off;
    types_hash_max_size    2048;
    types_hash_bucket_size 64;
    client_max_body_size   16M;

    # MIME
    include                mime.types;
    default_type           application/octet-stream;

    # Logging
    access_log             off;
    error_log              /var/log/nginx/error.log error;

    # Limits
    limit_req_log_level    warn;
    limit_req_zone         $binary_remote_addr zone=login:10m rate=10r/m;

    # SSL
    ssl_session_timeout    1d;
    ssl_session_cache      shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_tickets    off;

    # Diffie-Hellman parameter for DHE ciphersuites
    ssl_dhparam            /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;

    # Mozilla Intermediate configuration
    ssl_protocols          TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers            ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;

    # OCSP Stapling
    ssl_stapling           on;
    ssl_stapling_verify    on;
    resolver               1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 208.67.222.222 208.67.220.220 valid=60s;
    resolver_timeout       2s;

    # Connection header for WebSocket reverse proxy
    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        ""      close;
    }

    map $remote_addr $proxy_forwarded_elem {

        # IPv4 addresses can be sent as-is
        ~^[0-9.]+$        "for=$remote_addr";

        # IPv6 addresses need to be bracketed and quoted
        ~^[0-9A-Fa-f:.]+$ "for=\"[$remote_addr]\"";

        # Unix domain socket names cannot be represented in RFC 7239 syntax
        default           "for=unknown";
    }

    map $http_forwarded $proxy_add_forwarded {

        # If the incoming Forwarded header is syntactically valid, append to it
        "~^(,[ \\t]*)*([!#$%&'*+.^_`|~0-9A-Za-z-]+=([!#$%&'*+.^_`|~0-9A-Za-z-]+|\"([\\t \\x21\\x23-\\x5B\\x5D-\\x7E\\x80-\\xFF]|\\\\[\\t \\x21-\\x7E\\x80-\\xFF])*\"))?(;([!#$%&'*+.^_`|~0-9A-Za-z-]+=([!#$%&'*+.^_`|~0-9A-Za-z-]+|\"([\\t \\x21\\x23-\\x5B\\x5D-\\x7E\\x80-\\xFF]|\\\\[\\t \\x21-\\x7E\\x80-\\xFF])*\"))?)*([ \\t]*,([ \\t]*([!#$%&'*+.^_`|~0-9A-Za-z-]+=([!#$%&'*+.^_`|~0-9A-Za-z-]+|\"([\\t \\x21\\x23-\\x5B\\x5D-\\x7E\\x80-\\xFF]|\\\\[\\t \\x21-\\x7E\\x80-\\xFF])*\"))?(;([!#$%&'*+.^_`|~0-9A-Za-z-]+=([!#$%&'*+.^_`|~0-9A-Za-z-]+|\"([\\t \\x21\\x23-\\x5B\\x5D-\\x7E\\x80-\\xFF]|\\\\[\\t \\x21-\\x7E\\x80-\\xFF])*\"))?)*)?)*$" "$http_forwarded, $proxy_forwarded_elem";

        # Otherwise, replace it
        default "$proxy_forwarded_elem";
    }

    # Load configs
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    # api.ch.com
    server {
        listen                               443 ssl http2 reuseport;
        listen                               [::]:443 ssl http2 reuseport;
        server_name                          www.api.ch.com;
        root                                 /var/www/_letsencrypt;

        # SSL
        ssl_certificate                      /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.ch.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key                  /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.ch.com/privkey.pem;
        ssl_trusted_certificate              /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.ch.com/chain.pem;

        # security headers
        add_header X-XSS-Protection          "1; mode=block" always;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options    "nosniff" always;
        add_header Referrer-Policy           "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
        add_header Content-Security-Policy   "default-src 'self' http: https: ws: wss: data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; frame-ancestors 'self';" always;
        add_header Permissions-Policy        "interest-cohort=()" always;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;

        # . files
        location ~ /\.(?!well-known) {
            deny all;
        }

        # security.txt
        location /security.txt {
            return 301 /.well-known/security.txt;
        }

        location = /.well-known/security.txt {
            alias ~/security.txt;
        }

        # logging
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log combined buffer=512k flush=1m;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log error;

        # reverse proxy
        location / {
            proxy_pass                         http://api_server_prod:21347;
            proxy_set_header Host              $host;
            proxy_http_version                 1.1;
            proxy_cache_bypass                 $http_upgrade;

            # Proxy SSL
            proxy_ssl_server_name              on;

            # Proxy headers
            proxy_set_header Upgrade           $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection        $connection_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Forwarded         $proxy_add_forwarded;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;

            # Proxy timeouts
            proxy_connect_timeout              60s;
            proxy_send_timeout                 60s;
            proxy_read_timeout                 60s;
        }

        # favicon.ico
        location = /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off;
        }

        # robots.txt
        location = /robots.txt {
            log_not_found off;
        }

        # gzip
        gzip            on;
        gzip_vary       on;
        gzip_proxied    any;
        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_types      text/plain text/css text/xml application/json application/javascript application/rss+xml application/atom+xml image/svg+xml;
    }

    # non-www, subdomains redirect
    server {
        listen                  443 ssl http2;
        listen                  [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name             .api.ch.com;

        # SSL
        ssl_certificate         /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.ch.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.ch.com/privkey.pem;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.ch.com/chain.pem;

        # logging
        error_log               /var/log/nginx/error.log error;
        return                  301 https://www.api.ch.com$request_uri;
    }

    # HTTP redirect
    server {
        listen      80 reuseport;
        listen      [::]:80 reuseport;
        server_name .api.ch.com;

        # logging
        error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log error;

        # ACME-challenge
        location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
            allow all;
            root /var/www/_letsencrypt;
        }

        location / {
            return 301 https://www.api.ch.com$request_uri;
        }
    }
}
```

Questions

- Do i need to separately list out the domains for both https and http under allowed origins?
- Do i need to modify my nginx.conf file in any way to handle cors?
- Do i need to include localhost:8000 for allowed origins in production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*1. Do i need to separately list out the domains for both `https` and `http` under allowed origins?*

You can use `regExp` instead it can match both `http` and `https` and includes `subdomain` aslo:

```
import { NODE_ENV } from "common/constants";

export function getAllowedOrigins() {

  let allowedOrigins;
  if (NODE_ENV === "development") {
    allowedOrigins = /example\.com$/;
  } else if (NODE_ENV === "test") {
    allowedOrigins = /staging\.example\.com$/;
  } else if (NODE_ENV === "production") {
    allowedOrigins = "https://www.example.com"; // for production https prefered
  }
  return allowedOrigins;
}
```

*2. Do i need to modify my `nginx.conf` file in any way to handle cors?*

No, you don't need it even you can because controls in one place better the many. Let the express handle it.

*3. Do i need to include `localhost:8000` for allowed origins in production?*

Definitely not, Production is an isolated environment there is no need to include `localhost`

Comment: Careful: `/example.com$/` also matches `https://notexample.com`. Also`/staging.example.com$/` matches `https://stagingxexample.com`. All the `.` in those regular expressions should be escaped (`\.`).